# Javascript - changing color on specific value with if/else

Tags: javascript, magento

I included a character count to my magento short description text area. Now i want the  to change it's color when there is more than 10 characters type in the text area.

This is the code i have:

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {

    Element.insert( $('short_description').up().next().down('span'), { 
        'after': "<div id='short_description_counter'>Char count: <span id='short_description_counter_num'>"+$('short_description').getValue().length+"</span></div>"
    });

    Event.observe('short_description', 'keyup', function(event) {   
        $("short_description_counter_num").update(this.getValue().length);
    });

    var short_description_counter_num = "";
    if(short_description_counter_num > 10)
    {
        document.getElementById("short_description_counter_num").style.color="#FF0000";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("short_description_counter_num").style.color="#000000";
    }

});
```

It changes color when I change the > to <, but it does not happen on the fly while i type. in my text field.

The code is a modded version of this:
http://jsbin.com/isisur/2/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in these lines

```
var short_description_counter_num = "";
if(short_description_counter_num > 10)
```

you are comparing string with an integer.
 make sure both are `integers`

```
var short_description_counter_num = this.getValue().length;
```

http://jsbin.com/isisur/18/edit